# Calculating APR

Tags: loans, interest

If I have a loan at 5% interest over a year compounded semi-monthly does this loan have a higher APR compared to a loan at 5% compounded annually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, at an equal interest rate, the more times annually the principal is compounded, the higher the total will be.  The semi-monthly compound will cost you more.

This makes sense if you imagine that each time the interest is added, it is based on the current total.  If this happens more frequently, it will grow more frequently, resulting in a higher total over same given time.

Answer (score 2):

The compound interest formula is P(1+r/n)^nt.

You only want to know what the difference is if the number of times it is compounded changes, so with t = 1 year, you plug in .05 for r, the only variable left is n.

(1+.05/n)^n

For annual compounding, n = 1, which comes to 1.05 or an increase of 5%

For semiannual compounding, n = 2, which comes to 1.050625 or an increase of 5.0625%

Comment: Note that "continuous compounding" can be calculated as a limit, and comes out to a multiplier of e^(rt) (the constant e to the power of r times t), where t is time in years and r is the nominal rate. For one year at 5%, continuous compounding would come out to an increase of about 5.1271%. So while more frequent compounding does mean a higher real interest rate, the actual improvement diminishes rapidly with each step.

Comment: I thought about discussing Euler's constant, but that's not the question that was asked, so I chose to keep it simple.

Comment: Perfectly reasonable. I just tossed this in because the natural follow-on question is "so if quarterly compounding is good, is monthly compounding four times better and daily 90 times better?" -- and the answer is "No, it's asymptotic approach to a limit.

Comment: Yeah, monthly is pretty close to the limit, but daily will give you a few more pennies per thousand dollars.